# How to regulate the RPM of a mainspring powered gear without an escapement?

Tags: watch

I am building a watch and want to include a mechanism, where, upon the press of a button, the mainspring releases its energy causing the music box to play. Traditionally, the music box does not allow all energy to be released at once by using a wind resistance governor.

What can I do to introduce friction to a rotating gear in such a way that it does not cross "x" RPM despite the energy flow from the spring...however the friction also does not completely stop the gear.

Essentially, all I am trying to understand is how to cap the RPM speed of a gear (being powered by a mainspring/elastic potential energy)

Comment: May be worth a look: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/50853/10902

Comment: So you're asking for some sort of microgovernor.   Is the music box part of the watch, or does the watch "plug in" to an external music box?    Either way, possibly a very small "fan" enclosed in a nonlinear viscous fluid might emulate your wind resistance governor.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by frictional centrifugal governor. Such governors are commonly used in telephone disk dials. They are simple and reliable.